# PESTER - can i use it for powershell workflows?

Tags: automation, pester, powershell-workflow

Friends,
I am automating some infra related stuffs using powershell and converting that to workflows and running in SMA (Service Management Automation).

Lets say if I have to automate some linux and windows machine storage addition, they I create 1 main.ps1 workflow and call two child workflow's windows.ps1 and linux.ps1, 1 each for windows and linux storage addition. I have to put those 3 files in SMA and run them. Before that I wanted to test the whole automation functionality.

As per my knowledge pester is best fit for unit testing, i.e., each 3 files testing using pester separately.

My questions is, can i use pester in main.ps1 files and test the work flow in SMA? if not, do you suggest any best open-source tool for this?

Thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm fully understanding your question, but you can just dot source the other files in to one script and then Pester test them all together.